# Determining the encryption used based on string and salt

Tags: encryption, hash, theory

I'm reverse engineering a system that I've been tasked to understand. The system uses tokens and semi-randomised[1] timestamps (as the salt) and an unknown hashing function to generate random keys for authentication.

The strings it produces are 64 characters in length and there appears to be a pattern to the hashing. For example (based on fictional inputs and outputs of unrelated lengths as this question is theory):

```
salt: 135407067754316
token: aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd
```

This would produce:

```
hash: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ed41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

And then changing the salt:

```
salt: 13540707209819
token: aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd
```

Produces:

```
hash: d41d9g838fddb275e9800123ecf8427ed41d9g838fddb275e9800123ecf8427e
```

Which is *similar* to the first hash (first 3 characters always match), where the only difference in the generation is the key (the semi-randomised timestamp), which leads me to the conclusion that they're using some basic hashing that uses the randomised timestamp as the salt.

**Question** How would I go about narrowing down how they're encrypting or what function they're using? I can cause generation of any number of hashes I need (with the key and token available to me) however I cannot cause generation of hashes using my token and key of choice. The result is 64 characters in length.

Does a techique exist that will allow me to brute force the generation method if I have 100, 200, 500, 1000, 10000, 100000 examples of salts, tokens and the result?

[1] Semi randomised means they're taking the current timestamp (eg: 1354068826) and adding a random 5 length number to the end, to create something like 135406882613951)

Final note, I know nothing of encryption or hashing or security beyond the basic ideas (input value and salt, get hash).